# Swift: Setting rootViewController not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to start a new Swift project. This is my first time trying to create the views programatically. However it doesn't even look like my controller is being loaded? All I see is the launch screen and then a black screen when I load it onto the simulator.

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    NSLog("zrrrzz") // <------------------------------ Prints properly
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.rootViewController()
    return true
  }

  private func rootViewController() -> UIViewController {
    NSLog("zzz") // <---------------------------------- Does not print ????
    return MapViewController.init()
  }

}
```

MapViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I am a test label"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        NSLog("heyyyy!!") //<------------------------------ Also doesn't print ??
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Am I missing a step? I don't see any warnings / errors when I start the simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = self.rootViewController()
```

If the `window` property is `nil`, it will not execute your `self.rootViewController()` call.  You can read more about [calling methods with optional chaining in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID249) for details.

If you are trying to create your initial user interface in code, you will need to create a `UIWindow` instance and assign it to `self.window`.  This is done for you automatically when using a Storyboard.

**Disclaimer**: I haven't written this code in a few versions of iOS, so this may not be exactly correct, but it will get you going in the right direction:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let applicationFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
    let window = UIWindow(frame: applicationFrame)
    window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window

    return true
}
```

Comment: @MayankJain Why would it, it's from a full year ago.

Comment: yes you are right... I am facing the same issue in Swift 3  see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085021/initial-rootviewcontroller-is-not-setting-in-swift-3-0